# Не работает ответ success Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

При успешной отправке формы, по идее должно высветится оповещение с текстом message send, но страница просто перезагружается, при этом форма верно отрабатывает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'Registration.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            login: login,
            password: pass1,
            email: email,
            referral: referral
        },
        success: function(res) {
           console.log(login);
                    $('.alert').css('background','green');
                        Notification('message send');
                        return false


                },
                error: function(){                        
                    $('.alert').css('background','red');
                    Notification('Error!');
                    return false
                }    
    });
function Notification(Text) {
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = Text;
    $('.alert').animate({
        bottom: '10px',
        opacity: '1'
    }, 1000, function() {
        var alertHide = setInterval(function() {
            $('.alert').animate({
                bottom: '-100%',
                opacity: '0'
            }, 10000);
            clearInterval(alertHide);
        }, 10000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("your form selector").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // !!!
  $.ajax({
    ...
    error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      console.log(jqXHR);
    }
  });
});
```

`return false` в обработчиках `success` и `error` не нужны.

Comment: аякс отправляет данные в registration.php, но почему-то отрабатывает событие error, а не success

Comment: Давайте выясним, что за ошибка происходит.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Y63j6GU.png вот что выводит консоль, может какие-то конфликты с файлом Registration.php, т.к я из него возвращаю ошибки в json формате, допустим если mail повторяется и тд

Comment: @Ayurpwnz Ну вон же ошибка. Поставьте в `ajax` опциях `dataType: "text",` и выведите в `success`: `console.log(res);`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ZEYCDqV.png замазал только домен и вводимый mail

Comment: @Ayurpwnz Это html, а не JSON. Я не совсем понимаю, почему jQuery пытается его распарсить как JSON.

Comment: @Ayurpwnz Но ошибки, я так понимаю, больше нет?

Comment: да, ошибка пропала, осталось разобраться как выводить необходимые оповещения

Comment: @Ayurpwnz Рекомендую задать про это отдельный вопрос.